# Add score from full-text search MATCH together

Tags: mysql, select, nlp

I have two tables:

Table `pages`:

```
|id |title      |
+---+-----------+
|1  |Foxes      |
|2  |Pet dogs   |
```

Table `keywords`:

```
|id |page_id |phrase                |
+---+--------+----------------------+
|1  |1       |quick brown fox jumps |
|2  |1       |lazy dog              |
|3  |2       |caring for a dog      |
|4  |2       |pet dog               |
```

I am currently using this query:

```
SELECT pages.title, MATCH (phrase) AGAINST ('pet dog') as relevance
FROM pages
INNER JOIN keywords
ON pages.id = keywords.page_id
WHERE MATCH (phrase) AGAINST ('pet dog')
ORDER BY relevance DESC;
```

And I get this result:

```
|title |relevance            |
+------+---------------------+
|Dogs  |0.3780859112739563   |
|Foxes |0.015609688125550747 |
|Dogs  |0.015609688125550747 |
```

But I want each `title` to have only one `relevance`, so the `relevance` of each phrase appropriate to each `title` should be added together like this:

```
|title |relevance            |
+------+---------------------+
|dogs  |0.3936955994         |
|foxes |0.015609688125550747 |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add a `GROUP BY title` statement to your result set, thus records with same `title` will be aggregated into one group.
2. Call a `SUM` function to get the summation of `relevance` for each group.

So, this query may help you out:

```
SELECT title, SUM(relevance)
FROM
(
  SELECT pages.title, MATCH (phrase) AGAINST ('pet dog') as relevance
  FROM pages
  INNER JOIN keywords
  ON pages.id = keywords.page_id
  WHERE MATCH (phrase) AGAINST ('pet dog')
  ORDER BY relevance DESC
)
GROUP BY title;
```

Comment: @FrankerZ Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by the title and sum up the relevance score. The following query solves your problem:

```
SELECT title, SUM(MATCH (phrase) AGAINST ('pet dog' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) as relevance
FROM pages AS p
INNER JOIN keywords AS k ON p.id = k.page_id
GROUP BY title
HAVING relevance > 0
ORDER BY relevance DESC;
```

See **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/619353/9)**